# datatable could not be found

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

[image]
hello, I've seen many videos and in all of them with System.Data.SqlClient it works but with mine it doesn't find it and asks for System.Data but this one doesn't work

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: You need to add System.Data namespace at the top

Comment: read the error message VS is prompting you with, (assuming you spelt it correctly) that error generally means you need either a using statement, or a nuget package or something. if you hover over potential fixes VS often just does it for you

Comment: ^ Hover over the lightbulb > `Add System.Data`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Right-click Project.
- Left-click Add Reference.
- Left-click Assemblies.
- Find System.Data

[image: Add reference..]

[image: Example]

Comment: It would be good to show an example using the LightBulb...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and corrections. I'll keep it in mind for the next one.